# Variable tags Azure ARM JSON based

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

We are using the following template to deploy multiple resourcegroups by using an ARM template:

```
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroups": {
          "type": "array",
          "defaultValue": [
            "RG1",
            "RG2",
            "RG3"
          ]
        }
    "resources": [
          {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('ResourceGroups')[copyIndex()])]",
            "copy": {
              "name": "resourcegroupcopy",
              "count": "[length(parameters('ResourceGroups'))]",
              "mode": "serial"
            },
"properties": {},
        "tags": {}
```

We also want to script the Azure Tags on these resourcegroups. The issue however is, not all resourcegroups we created need the same tags. They vary depending on the resourch group.

For example: RG1 needs Tag1, RG2 needs Tag2, etc.

How do I put this into my script?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: This is what variables are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the answer is: it depends on your exact requirements, but generally 2 approaches: if() function, object mapping. Either of those can be combined with union() function. create a variable for each tag you require:

```
"tag1": {
    "something": "bla-bla"
},
"tag2": {
    "somethingElse": "bla-bla-bla"
}
```

then, you can do something like this in the resource code:

```
"tags": "[if(condition(something goes here, depending on your needs), variable('tag1'), variables('tag2'))]"
```

you can have more if statements combined one inside the other and you can also use union() function to merge tags (although, not practical). union(variables('tag1'), variables('tag2')).

Another (more manageable way, on a scale), is using a mapper to "calculate" tag property. You want tag1 on rg1, tag2 on rg2, tag3 on rg3. In short what happens: you are retrieving a variable, which name equals to value of the property which in turn equals to the name of the object. Confusing? here's an example. create a new variable:

```
"mapper": {
    "rg1": "tag1",
    "rg2": "tag2",
    "rg3": "tag3",
}
```

and then, in your resource you can do this:

```
"tags": "[variables(variables('mapper')[variables(parameters('ResourceGroups')[copyIndex()]))])]"
          ^         ^                  ^          ^ name of the property would be RG1\RG2\RG3 depending on where you are in the loop. this would return value of the property, so tag1 or tag2 or tag3
          ^         ^                  ^ access properties of the object you get from the previous function (variables('mapper'))
          ^         ^ get variable called 'mapper'. you will get an object
          ^ get variable value called tag1 or tag2 or tag3
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much! Two more questions. What if all resourcegroups need the same tags, but different values? Is there some kind of best practice for this? And in case of the mapper, what if rg1 needs both tag1 and tag2?

Comment: well, you'd have to pull values from somewhere. as arm templates do not really offer something like a centralized storage you would need to do that either before running the template and pass the value as the parameter or you would need to implement some creating arm template strategies ;)